# Backslash symbol "\" in R environment within the string block

Tags: r-exams

I have several string blocks in the R environment with `"\"` which is used to describe the latex symbols. However, when I use the expressions with a backslash `"\"` or double backslashes `"\\"` within `\Sexpr{}` in the question or answer parts, they do not really function as expected. Is there any way to properly use backslashes in R exams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard R strings the backslash is the escape symbol and hence it also needs to be escaped itself. So you need `"\\alpha"` to denote the string *\alpha*. However, wehn you use `\Sexpr{}` you need to escape twice, once for reading and once for writing. Thus, you need `"\\\\alpha"` in that case.

If you write German umlaut characters it becomes even worse because the `"` also has to be escaped, e.g., `sch\\\\\"on"` to write *schön* in  LaTeX. But if you don't use this very often, it's not worth trying to remeber it. Instead apply the strategy from `fortunes::fortune(365)`:

> *When in doubt, keep adding slashes until it works.*
> -- Joran Elias (on how to escape a backslash in R)
>    Stackoverflow (March 2015)

Comment: Excellent! Many Thanks, Achim. That really works. Yesterday, I spent almost an hour to figure out how to deal with slashes but failed. I liked your example from Deutsche.

Comment: I also should add that starting from R 4.0.0 R also has support for literal strings. Thus, you can use `r"(\alpha)"` with a single backslash instead of `"\\alpha"`. This will not help you with `\Sexpr{}`, though.